# How to unnest an integer array represented as a BLOB?

Tags: sqlite, blob

SQLite doesn’t have native support for arrays. I would think that my method (thinking outlined below) of making a custom BLOB encoding would be a fairly common workaround (yes, I need an array rather than normalizing the table). The benefit of representing an integer array as a BLOB is primarily the space savings, for example:

```
13,24,455,23,64789
```

Stored as TEXT will take up 18 bytes (commas included, making assumptions here). But if one were to store the above TEXT in a custom encoded BLOB format it would look like this:

```
0x000D001801C7FD15
```

Where every number is assumed to take up 2 Bytes (0 to 65,535 or 0000 to FFFF). This BLOB, to my understanding, would then be 10 Bytes. This is nearly half the size as storing it in a delimited TEXT format. This space savings would also be magnified by the number of rows and the number of integers in the array.

Is there a good way of unnesting a BLOB by width? Say that I want to unnest the BLOB so that each row represents an integer. Can I take the above BLOB and turn it into this?

| id | number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 000D |
| 2 | 0018 |
| 3 | 01C7 |
| 4 | FD15 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite's [`HEX()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#hex) function

> interprets its argument as a BLOB and returns a string which is the
> upper-case hexadecimal rendering of the content of that blob.

After you get the blob as a string use `SUBSTR()` to slice it in 4 char parts:

```
WITH cte(id) AS (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5))
SELECT HEX(t.col) hex_col, 
       c.id,
       SUBSTR(HEX(t.col), (c.id - 1) * 4 + 1, 4) number
FROM tablename t JOIN cte c
ORDER BY t.rowid, c.id;
```

Or, with a recursive CTE to generate dynamically the list of values 1..n:

```
WITH cte(id) AS (
  SELECT 1 
  UNION ALL
  SELECT id + 1
  FROM cte
  WHERE id < 5
)
SELECT HEX(t.col) hex_col, 
       c.id,
       SUBSTR(HEX(t.col), (c.id - 1) * 4 + 1, 4) number
FROM tablename t JOIN cte c
ORDER BY t.rowid, c.id;
```

Change `col` to the name of your blob column.

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=fc9ee99da07b8102b193d97f47ee90fa).

Comment: This works really well! Just a quick comment: my BLOBs sometimes contain over a hundred integers. Is there a way to generate the cte table dynamically? or perhaps a shorthand way to express a range? (e.g. 1...150) I ask because my range will always be 1 through the length of the HEX(t.col) divided by 4.

Comment: @johngreen283  check my 2nd query.